# How to add bottom box and text to a picture in linux

Tags: css, image, imagemagick

I am trying to achieve a result similar to this

[image]

Instead I would like to have the box added to the very bottom, roughly covering 1/8th of the screen.

I've found that text can be added with `convert` tool or `ImageMagick` but I am having hard time understanding how to add the box/bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

You could try something like this. First, load the beetle image and enable a transparency layer so we can later get the semi-transparent black effect. Then, inside parentheses, start some *"aside processing"* where we copy the original picture, resize it to 12% of its original height and make it black. Then we set the transparency to 50% which completes the *"aside processing"*. We now set the `-gravity` to South so that when we composite the black box, it appears at the bottom - this also sets the anchor position for the annotation which comes next.

```
convert beetle.jpg -alpha on                                    \
  \( +clone -scale x12% -threshold 101% -channel A -fx "0.5" \) \
  -gravity south -composite                                     \
  -fill white -pointsize 24 -annotate 0,0 "Probably a Beetle" result.jpg
```

[image]

**Method 2**

Here is another way of doing it which, although it takes two steps, might be more akin to your way of thinking. First, get **ImageMagick** to work out the dimensions of the dark box and save them:

```
box=$(convert beetle.jpg -format "0,%[fx:int(h*0.88)] %w,%h" info:)
```

If you run `echo $box` you will see something like:

```
0,253 432,288
```

Then use that variable like this:

```
convert beetle.jpg -gravity south      \
  -fill '#0008' -draw "rectangle $box" \
  -fill white -pointsize 24 -annotate 0,0 "Probably a Beetle" result.jpg
```

Comment: With version 7 you should still be able to do this in one line?convert beetle.jpg -gravity south      \
  -fill '#0008' -draw "rectangle "0,%[fx:int(h*0.88)] %w,%h"" \
  -fill white -pointsize 24 -annotate 0,0 "Probably a Beetle" result.jpg I am unable to test this at the moment.

Comment: @Bonzo My version 7.0.3-5 doesn't seem to accept `... -draw "rectangle 0,%[fx:int(h*0.88)] %w,%h" ...` Nor double quotes inside single quotes, nor single quotes inside double quotes, nor escaped double quotes inside double quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Marks second example using Imagemagick V7.03 but on windows so I had to replace any ' with " also you need to use magick instead of convert with V7 otherwise it uses the V6 version and it will fail

```
magick input -gravity south -fill "#0008" -draw "rectangle 0,%[fx:int(h*0.88)] %w,%h" -fill white -pointsize 24 -annotate 0,0 "Probably a Beetle" result
```